# self.apos.users.find doesn't return the correct record

Tags: apostrophe-cms

This relates to the other question I asked in regard to auto login. I thought it was working because the cookie gets set, however, now when I check the query, it always returns the same user "admin". If I run this query in mongo:

db.getCollection('aposUsersSafe').find({username: 'lance'})

I get the user "lance", but using the code posted in the answer here:

[Auto login users to Apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836621/auto-login-users-to-apostrophe)

I always return the same user "admin" on matter any valid username I supply.

```
 self.apos.users.find({username: 'lance'}).permission(false).toObject(function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return callback(null);
                }

                console.log(user);
  });
```

This looks basic, but I cant figure out why the query it won't return any record but this same "admin" record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the use of users.find in a base class and saw that it has the request object passed as a param to find(). Adding this param returns the expected result. Looks like this was just left out in the snippet in the original answer, but it's working now.

self.apos.users.find(req, {username: 'lance'})

Comment: Correct Lance, that's the right fix. I fixed this omission in the original answer. Sorry for the hassle!